# Flutter: How to send a model from the API to other screen using flutter_local_notification

Tags: flutter, notifications

I have a problem when implementation [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications).

The problem is, how to send custom data from the notification? Because I see on the [example](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/tree/master/flutter_local_notifications/example) only send a `payload`. Not give the example of how to send `title`, `body`, or `custom data` like my case (want to send model data from the API).

So how to solve my case? Because I already thinking about it still not give me a solution, also already googling it.

As you can see below, on my function already add the parameter model `Articles` and add it to `title` and `body` to make my content on the notification is dynamically based on API. But how to send that model to another screen? because the property `payload` only support for `String` but my model is not a `String`

```
static Future<void> showNotification(
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin,
      Articles articles) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'your channel id', 'your channel name', 'your channel description',
        importance: Importance.Max, priority: Priority.High, ticker: 'ticker');

    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();

    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0, articles.title, articles.description, platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: 'i want to drop articles parameter here'); // the problem here
  }
```

And this is my `Article` model

```
class BundleData {
  final Source source;
  final Articles articles;

  BundleData(this.source, this.articles);
}

class Articles {
  Articles({
    this.source,
    this.author,
    this.title,
    this.description,
    this.url,
    this.urlToImage,
    this.publishedAt,
    this.content,
  });

  Source source;
  String author;
  String title;
  String description;
  String url;
  String urlToImage;
  String publishedAt;
  String content;

  factory Articles.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Articles(
    source: Source.fromJson(json["source"]),
    author: json["author"],
    title: json["title"],
    description: json["description"],
    url: json["url"],
    urlToImage: json["urlToImage"],
    publishedAt: json["publishedAt"],
    content: json["content"] == null ? null : json["content"],
  );
}

class Source {
  Source({
    this.id,
    this.name,
  });

  int id;
  String name;

  factory Source.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Source(
    id: json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
  );
}
```

As you can see again, the listen is only support for `String`, but when the notification is clicked and open the detail page, it's need data from the model that getting from the API.

```
static void configureSelectNotificationSubject(
      BuildContext context, String route) {
    selectNotificationSubject.stream.listen((String payload) async { // because i need to get the articles model from the notification to arguments
      await Navigator.pushNamed(context, route, arguments: BundleData(payload));
    });
  }
```

And also when we initialize the notification in the `main`, the property `onSelectNotification` only supports for `String` only, can't support for custom data like adding a model.

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: (String payload) async { // because this property only support String only, so how to send a model from API?
      if (payload != null) {
        print('notification payload: ' + payload);
      }
      selectNotificationSubject.add(payload);
```

Anyone can tell me how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert your model into JSON format that you will decode/encode. I don't know what variables are inside your `Articles` and `Source` classes but supposedly you could try something like that :

```dart
class BundleData {
  final Source source;
  final Articles articles;

  BundleData(this.source, this.articles);

  factory BundleData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return BundleData(Source.fromJson(json['source']), Articles.fromJson(json['articles']));
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "source": this.source.toJson(),
      "articles": this.articles.toJson()
    };
  }
}
```

You will need to create a factory `fromJson` and also a method `toJson` for both `Source` and `Articles` if you go with this solution.

Then you you could pass your parameters like this :

```dart
BundleData bundleData = BundleData(/* some source */, /* some articles */);
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
  0, articles.title, articles.description, platformChannelSpecifics,
  payload: jsonEncode(bundleData.toJson()));
```

Then get back your model like this:

```dart
static void configureSelectNotificationSubject(BuildContext context, String route) {
  selectNotificationSubject.stream.listen((String payload) async {
    await Navigator.pushNamed(context, route, arguments: BundleData.fromJson(jsonDecode(payload)));
  });
}
```

Comment: If the data from the API (JSON), so this is the only solution? But how if the data not from the API? I mean the data is not JSON format?

Comment: And also I already add the code for `Article` and `Source` class